# What are the differences among Top Level Window, Child window, Dialog(modal) window and non-dialog (modeless) windows?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms

Can any body please tell me how to distinguish among them?

I have difficulty in understanding what are the distinguishing factors for top level child windows vs dialog/non-dialog window? 
Can the top level window be dialog/non-dialog window? 
Can the child window be dialog/non-dialog window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top-level forms are owned by the desktop, whereas child forms belong to another form; this means that closing or minimising the owning form will also affect the child form.

Modal forms/dialogs block the calling thread until the form is closed, whereas modeless forms allow you to interact with other forms in the application while shown. Any form can be modal/modeless, regardless of whether it is a top-level or child form - however the default behaviour for modal dialogs is to be owned by the form that caused them to be shown.

Comment: Does that mean you could have a child window which is modeless to it's parent?

Comment: @ZammyPage Yes, and this is quite common; for example, in a text editor, the Find feature might be a modeless child window, allowing you to continue to interact with the main window (scrolling through the document, etc) while the Find window is still on the screen.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I'll mark this as an answer. The reason I asked this question is I find it hard to understand why XBAP doesn't allow me to create a modal window. Also why can't I use the child window in the XBAP?

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Modal

> A modal form or **dialog box** must be closed or hidden before you can continue working with the rest of the application.

Modeless

> Modeless forms let you shift the focus between the form and another form without having to close the initial form.

A top-level window can be either modal (dialog) or modeless.

A top-level window is owned by the desktop, thus it cannot be a child of a parent form.

A child window, owned by a parent form, **is not** a top-level form, because it has a parent. But it can be on top **in the Z order**, and can be modal or modeless depending on how it is displayed, with either `ShowDiaglog()` or `Show()` respectively.

Comment: are you sure top level window can be modal ?

Comment: Yes. To display a form modally use the `ShowDialog()` method.  The `Form.Modal` property can be used to test the modality of a displayed form. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Consider expanding on _"top level window"_ and explaining _"child window"_ as mentioned in the OP's title.  Currently you're only explaining the difference between _modal_ and _modeless_ windows.

Answer (score 1):

Top Level Window: The windows which are not owned by any other windows and hence they govern their own lifetime. Example Notepad window

Child window: The windows which are owned by some other window. This other window itself could be Top-level or Child. Example Edit box or status bar of Notepad, so if you close Notepad window edit box, status bar etc windows are gone.

Modal window: The window which blocks current threads execution until it is alive. If it is a child window then any interaction with its parent window will be blocked. Example Font dialog box of Notepad, if you open Font window, you can not type anything on Notepad window.

Modeless windows: The window which doesnt block current thread's execution when it is alive so if it is a child window it allows you to interact with its parent. example Find dialog box of Notepad, if you press Ctrl+F and open Find window, then you can put it aside and continue typing on main Notepad window.

Important point, a window can either be Child or Top level but cannot be both.

Hope this helps.